# Bypassing devise when using a gem that mounts an engine in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, devise, http-authentication

I'm using a gem that loads an engine to simplify my handing of webhooks.

```
# config/routes.rb
mount anEngine, at: '/my-chosen-path' # provide a custom path
```

My problem is that `ApplicationController` is implementing devise for authentication on all routes.  I'd like for the route provided by this engine to only be HTTP basic authentication, and to bypass devise completely.

I'm not sure what to do.  Help?

Answer (score 0):

You can specify the routes for that devise should not authenticate:

```
unauthenticated do
  mount anEngine, at: '/my-chosen-path' # provide a custom path
end
```

Source: [Devise Wiki](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/wiki/How-To:-Define-resource-actions-that-require-authentication-using-routes.rb)

Further reading:
https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/issues/2393

Comment: This didn't work either, still getting the same 401 on the route defined at `'/my-chosen-path'`, so I'm looking to see what else could be conflicting.